# How to filter an array from an Observable to get shallow copies instead of deep ones?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

My component uses some data (an array of "ksr" items which have a `code` property that may be considered as an id) loaded via xhr to an Observable

```
dictionaries = {
  ksr$: this.dictionaryService.fetchDictionaryByName('KSR'),
  ...
}
```

and some portion of it is filtered into another Observable like this:

```
formSuggestions = {
  ksrCodes$: this.dictionaries.ksr$.pipe(map((plainKsrArray: Array<any>) =>
    plainKsrArray.filter(ksrItem => ksrItem.levelName == "position"
  )),
  ...
}
```

I expected that once data is loaded, the items in `.formSuggestions` are shallow copies of those in `.dictionaries`, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Specifically, the following test function

```
async debugDictionariesAndSuggestions() {
  let dictionary = await this.dictionaries.ksr$.toPromise();
  let dItem = dictionary.find(item => item.code == '01.11.11.01.1.01.01-0001');
  let suggestions = await this.formSuggestions.ksrCodes$.toPromise();
  let sItem = suggestions.find(item => item.code == '01.11.11.01.1.01.01-0001');
  console.log('found by code:', dItem, sItem, dItem == sItem ? 'same' : 'not same');
  console.log(JSON.stringify(dItem) == JSON.stringify(sItem) ? 'they look the same' : 'they look different');
}
```

finds the items in both `dictionary` and `suggestions`, but reports those to be not the same thing (although all the nested properties of `dItem` and `sItem` are the same, reports "they look the same"). Why is that and how can I modify treating such data from observables (how can I filter `dictionaries.ksr$` to  `formSuggestions.ksrCodes$`) so that I have the latter consisting of items from the former (shallow copies)?

Comment: Every time you subscribe to an http observable, a new request is sent, and a new response is obtained. `ksr$.toPromise()` subscribes once, and `ksrCodes$.toPromise()` subscribes a second time.

Comment: @JBNizet right, that what I've feared. But is there some approach to create an Observable once and use it in several parts of code without making multiple requests? I use it in props via `| async` pipe and also would like to use in some methods of the component. Hmm.. looks like I have to subscribe in `ngOnInit` and fill other properties of component once the dictionary is loaded..

Comment: You can use the shareReplay or share operator, for example. Or better, you use the smart/dumb components principle, subscribe to the ksr$ observable with async a single time in the smart component, and pass the array as input to the dumb component, which can filter the array to get its ksrCodes.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks, this is indeed helpful, I've posted an answer showing how I went about this. Perhaps you are right that it is a good idea to reuse data by creating a child dumb component that handles it once request is done, but in my case this is a root component and for now I'll use the `shareReplay` operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @JBNizet has pointed, the `shareReplay` operator is a very simple way to fix that. A normal behavior of an observable derived from an http service observable is - each subscription (in my case promisified ones: `await this.dictionaries.ksr$.toPromise()` and `await this.formSuggestions.ksrCodes$.toPromise()`) triggers a new request. But if I modify it like this:

```
dictionaries = {
  ksr$: this.dictionaryService.fetchDictionaryByName('KSR').pipe(shareReplay()),
  ...
}
```

the `dictionaries.ksr$` observable and derived ones trigger only one request and the resulting values are shared which is what I was looking for.